# Laravel Queues - downloading PDF File

Tags: laravel, redis, puppeteer

I´m using Laravel 5.8.35 as my app framework, and npm puppeteer to convert blade views into pdf files, and it´s all working fine if I do it syncronously like this:

```
public function pdf_puppet() {
    return PDF::loadUrl('https://www.boltra.com.mx/test')
                ->download();
}
```

But if I try to queue this process, either by creating a Job or on a simple closure like:

```
dispatch(function() {
    return PDF::loadUrl('https://www.boltra.com.mx/test')
                ->download();
});
```

I get nothing; not a worker error and not even a record on the failed jobs table, just the blank screen. I know my redis queues are working fine, since I am using them for other tasks successfully, the worker is reset and started, redis is running and other queues work as expected, it´s only the pdf downloads that seem to ignore commands. I´ve ran php artisan queue:listen and both the dispatch and the job are being reported as processed with no errors, but I'm still not getting my pdf file. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: You cannot use queuing when downloading files. Queuing disconnects a process (like the PDF rendering) from your web request. Downloading a file can only be done synchronously. You can render the PDF in the background and send a link to the user though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Namoshek... your comment confirms my suspicions. Oddly enough, this fact is not mentioned in any of the docs. Cheers!

Comment: What package are you using exactly?

Comment: @Namoshek - I´m using Puppeteer [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer) through a package called Laravel - Browsershot [link](https://packalyst.com/packages/package/faustbrian/laravel-browsershot). This gives me pixel perfect results and is blazing fast. If you have not tried it, I recommend you do. Cheers!